# Нужна ли под цифрой запятая

Tags: синтаксис

В то время, когда происходило действие этого рассказа, валы были еще покрыты зарослями жимолости и боярышника(3) и в них гнездились птицы.
Нужна ли под цифрой запятая? Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна, там общее придаточное.

Answer (score 2):

В главной части сложноподчинённого предложения есть общий для двух предложений "валы были еще покрыты зарослями жимолости и боярышника(3) и в них гнездились птицы" второстепннный член предложения - обстоятельство  ***в то время*** (не путаем с союзом В ТО ВРЕМЯ КАК). При наличии общего второстепенного члена запятая между двумя простыми предложениями  не ставится.

А придаточное определительное с КОГДА уже относится к существительному ВРЕМЯ. Время (какое?).